# customlayout as mvp in fragment mvp

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp, android-mvp

I've been practising the MVP pattern in android.
My question is related to how to design the situation where you have a fragment with a custom layout.(see the below layout)
[customlayout in fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9gFM.jpg)

There are 2 cardviews in the customlayout:
- if you click on the friends cardview, a dialogfragment will be displayed showing a customadapter whose data comes from fetching the local DB
- if you click on the others cardview, a dialogfragment will be displayed showing a customadapter whose data comes from a server.
You can check the people in this adapter and if you click OK, the images of the checked people will be displayed in the cardview

I have made the fragment a view as part of an MVP construct but I got stuck.
Is it a good idea to create the customlayout as an MVP construct as well? or not just the layout, but the cardviews, too?
And if yes, then these "nested" MVPs how would they send the data(the friends & the others) back to the host fragment/presenter when I click the Save Button?

Or am I overcomplicating this simple fragment-layout architecture?
Any suggestions are appreciated

The fragment implements the below View:

```
public interface CreateEventContract {
    interface View extends BaseView<Presenter>{
        void showStartDateDateDialog();
        void showStartDateTimeDialog(LocalDate selectedDate);
        void showPlaceMapActivity();
        void saveButtonClicked();
        boolean isActive();
    }
    interface Presenter extends BasePresenter {
        void startDateDateDialog();
        void startDateTimeDialog(LocalDate selectedDate);
        void place();
        void saveEvent();
    }
}
```

and the CustomLayout:
[customLayout gist](https://gist.github.com/Klesz/bd20df398c555de75a4ebeff397e65e7)

Comment: Please post some code and what errors are you getting?

Comment: @AbhayBohra  I dont get any errors because I dont know how to implement the layout or the 2 cardviews in the layout in MVP(or should I use MVP for the layout or the 2cardviews ) in this scenario. That is why I am asking the question. It is kind of an architectural design question.

Answer (score 1):

In that situation, I think one could be guided by the **tablet MVP example** on GitHub, the [Android Architecture Blueprints](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/dev-todo-mvp-tablet/).

[image: MVP tablet mode]

**Transferred to your case**, your structure could be something like this

[image: MVP diagramm]

The views are reporting (e.g who's been checked) to a common Presenter, who is manipulating the views through their particular Presenter.